# concatenar dos salidas for each o hacerlas en uno solo java

Tags: java, java-8

Consulta tengo dos foreach cada uno de 81 registros

```
        listat = personNE.list();
        listap = parametrosEspNE.list();  


        for(ParametrosEsp pe : listap ){
           pw.prinln(String.valueOf(pe.getVALOR()+"|")); 

             }
        for(Person p : listat){         

               pw.prinln(String.valueOf(p.getCODIGO_DOC()+"|"+p.getCEDULA()+"|"+"1"+"|"));

        }
```

Cuando pongo la llave debajo me repite 81 veces, y luego de nuevo 81 ¿Cómo puedo solucionar o concatenar los dos print pero en orden?

El resultado me muestra asi:

|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
|1.23|
01|912358342||
01|912358353||
01|912358321||
01|912358213||
01|912358344||
01|912432333||
01|912358345||
01|912358346||
01|912358376||
01|234324344||
01|423432432||
01|423545466||

y quiero q me salga asi

|1.23|01|912358342||
|1.23|01|912358353||
|1.23|01|912358321||
|1.23|01|912358344||
|1.23|01|912432333||
|1.23|01|912358345||
|1.23|01|912358346||
|1.23|01|912358376||
|1.23|01|234324344||
|1.23|01|423432432||
|1.23|01|423545466||

Comment: vos queres imprimir 1 y 1 de cada lista? en ese orden? podes pone un ejemplo de tu salida actual y uno de lo que queres como salida?

Comment: No se que son todos esos numeros. Podes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la informacion ahi?

Comment: Son lo que vota q es en formato texto

Comment: Si pero toda esa info debe ir en la pregunta.

Comment: ya lo modifique lo que quiero es concatenar los dos foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu única solución es usar un for loop

```
listat = personNE.list();
listap = parametrosEspNE.list(); 

if (listat.size() == listap.size()){
  int iteraciones = listat.size();

  for(int i = 0; i < iteraciones; i++) {
    pw.println(
      String.valueOf(listap.get(i).getVALOR()+"|") + 
      String.valueOf(listat.get(i).getCODIGO_DOC() + "|"+listat.get(i).getCEDULA()+"|"+"1"+"|")
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Lo probare mirando el código creo q así sera mejor gracias